# Can't find the apk or aab file on google developer console

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console

I can't find the apk or aab file on google play developers console which is published and visible on android store but the apk and package of that app not found.

Please provide any guide or solution of this Issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it works for my app. I'm not sure if it's the same for everyone, depending on settings etc.

- Click "App bundle explorer" in the left sidebar.
- Find the version you want to download, and click the blue arrow to the right.
- Click the Downloads tab.
- Next to Distribution APK, click the download button.